# Make this python loop algorithm shorter (mathematics invloved)

Tags: python, loops, mathematical-optimization, mathematical-expressions

For sake of learning i opt for not using any additional libraries.

Goal of this algorithm to break lit `lst` into chunks 8 records each.
And additionally load the values from dictionary `dct` for records of `lst` 1-8, 9-16, 17-24.

Trying to avoid unnecessary `for loops` when possible, i come up with this solution.

```
dct = {1:'one', 2:'two', 3:'three', 4:'four', 5:'five', 6:'six', 7:'seven', 8:'eight'}

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]

loop = 0
for record in lst:
    print(f'record id: {record:<10} dct id: {record-loop:<10} dct value: {dct.get(record - loop)}')


    if record % 8 == 0:
        loop += 8
        print('--- loop finished ---')
```

this output

```
record id: 1          dct id: 1          dct value: one
record id: 2          dct id: 2          dct value: two
record id: 3          dct id: 3          dct value: three
record id: 4          dct id: 4          dct value: four
record id: 5          dct id: 5          dct value: five
record id: 6          dct id: 6          dct value: six
record id: 7          dct id: 7          dct value: seven
record id: 8          dct id: 8          dct value: eight
--- loop finished ---
record id: 9          dct id: 1          dct value: one
record id: 10         dct id: 2          dct value: two
record id: 11         dct id: 3          dct value: three
record id: 12         dct id: 4          dct value: four
record id: 13         dct id: 5          dct value: five
record id: 14         dct id: 6          dct value: six
record id: 15         dct id: 7          dct value: seven
record id: 16         dct id: 8          dct value: eight
--- loop finished ---
record id: 17         dct id: 1          dct value: one
record id: 18         dct id: 2          dct value: two
record id: 19         dct id: 3          dct value: three
record id: 20         dct id: 4          dct value: four
record id: 21         dct id: 5          dct value: five
record id: 22         dct id: 6          dct value: six
record id: 23         dct id: 7          dct value: seven
record id: 24         dct id: 8          dct value: eight
--- loop finished ---
```

Can someone with more mathematical experience suggest how can i get rid of variable `loop` altogether along with this section

```
if record % 8 == 0:
    loop += 8
```

and instead use some mathematical formula instead of `record - loop`

If i am simply using `dct.get(record % 8)` i am getting wrong result since `record % 8` produces this code

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0
```

I need

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Of course i could use a barbaric fix like this `((record - 1) % 8) + 1` to make it work, but i am sure there's more clean and more readable way of doing it.

Comment: The `print('--- loop finished ---')` is a lie.  The loop doesn't finish only when the `if` statement is true.  It finishes at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: I think your barbaric fix is the right way to do this. At least, it's the solution I've always landed on when using modulus in this way.

Comment: Indeed, what you call a *barbaric fix* is the usual way of doing it. Ask anyone who works with linearly stored matrices how they get the columns and rows and that's the usual way. Integer division and modulus.

Comment: Each dict id is just `(record - 1) % 8 + 1`. Another way of looking at this is that the dict id is really related to the *index* of each record, and it is a "coincidence" that `lst[i] == i + 1`. `for i, record in enumerate(lst): dct_id = (i % 8) + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be perfect. The only way I guess to reduce the loop is : to create a list with multiples of 8 say eight_mult, and providing a conditional statement like `if record in eight_mult: print('--- loop finished ---')`.

```
dct = {1:'one', 2:'two', 3:'three', 4:'four', 5:'five', 6:'six', 7:'seven', 8:'eight'}

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
eight_mult = [x*8 for x in range(1,4)]

loop = 0
for record in lst:
    print(f'record id: {record:<10} dct id: {record-loop:<10} dct value: {dct.get(record - loop)}')


    if record in eight_mult: print('--- loop finished ---')
```

Edit:
If your intention is to reduce the size of the code, in the second line: Instead of listing out all the 24 numbers, you can simply declare like `lst = [x for x in range(1,25)]`

Comment: `loop finished` was only used for debugging it was not intended to be kept.

Comment: If that is the thing, there is no need of changing in the OP's code

Answer (score 1):

The chunk size is the length of `dct.keys()`. Whenever the modulus is zero you want to use the chunk size as the key.

```py
dct = {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three', 4: 'four', 5: 'five', 6: 'six', 7: 'seven', 8: 'eight'}
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]

chunk_size = len(dct)

for record in lst:
    mod_value = record % chunk_size
    key = mod_value if mod_value else chunk_size
    print(f'record id: {record:<10} dct id: {key:<10} dct value: {dct.get(key)}')
```

Comment: Looks good, but for my mind its not easy to comprehend so i improved my own approach a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a misunderstanding about how loops work.

Each loop finishes at the bottom of the code block.

```py
loop = 0
for record in lst:
    # code here
    loop += 1
    print('--- loop finished ---')
```

In the case of your lst, you're going to make 24 loops.

However, it would appear you're not looking for the loop number but rather a counter of 1-8.

```py
counter = 1
for record in lst:
    value = dct.get(counter)
    print(f'{record =:<10} {counter = :<10} {value = }')
    if record % 8 == 0:
        counter = 1
    else:
        counter += 1
```

```
record = 1          counter = 1          value = 'one'
record = 2          counter = 2          value = 'two'
record = 3          counter = 3          value = 'three'
record = 4          counter = 4          value = 'four'
record = 5          counter = 5          value = 'five'
record = 6          counter = 6          value = 'six'
record = 7          counter = 7          value = 'seven'
record = 8          counter = 8          value = 'eight'
-- counter reset --
record = 9          counter = 1          value = 'one'
record = 10         counter = 2          value = 'two'
record = 11         counter = 3          value = 'three'
record = 12         counter = 4          value = 'four'
record = 13         counter = 5          value = 'five'
record = 14         counter = 6          value = 'six'
record = 15         counter = 7          value = 'seven'
record = 16         counter = 8          value = 'eight'
-- counter reset --
record = 17         counter = 1          value = 'one'
record = 18         counter = 2          value = 'two'
record = 19         counter = 3          value = 'three'
record = 20         counter = 4          value = 'four'
record = 21         counter = 5          value = 'five'
record = 22         counter = 6          value = 'six'
record = 23         counter = 7          value = 'seven'
record = 24         counter = 8          value = 'eight'
-- counter reset --
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested *for* loop. You don't need the *lst* list

```
dct = {
    1: "one",
    2: "two",
    3: "three",
    4: "four",
    5: "five",
    6: "six",
    7: "seven",
    8: "eight",
}

for i in range(0, 24, 8):
    for j in range(i+1, i+9):
        print(f'record id: {j:<10} dct id: {j-i:<10} dct value: {dct.get(j-i)}')
    print('--- loop finished ---')
```

Comment: The OP already wants to reduce the loop it seems.

Comment: I was trying to optimize speed and make it more simple to read rather than add more loops.

Comment: @RomanToasov Take a look at the *timeit* module. Run some tests. You may be surprised at how fast this is

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it a bit i simplified it like this instead of using confusing formula `((record - 1) % 8) + 1` i added index for `lst` using `enumerate()` so it start with `0` and then formula become `(idx % 8) + 1` which is same as `idx % 8 + 1` then i did not need anymore the variable `loop`.

`print('--- loop finished ---')` was there for debugging information only so i did remove it.

```
dct = {1:'one', 2:'two', 3:'three', 4:'four', 5:'five', 6:'six', 7:'seven', 8:'eight'}

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]

for idx, record in enumerate(lst):
    print(f'{record % 8}  record id: {record:<10} dct id: {(idx % 8) + 1:<10} dct value: {dct.get((idx % 8) + 1)}')
```